# WSDL XSD consuming in java

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

Im getting XML Validation Error. Trying to consume wsdl from file.
not able to track what the issue here. tried out my solution but didnt worked.
Existing xsds size are too long, don't know how to attached xml files.

Current situation is having wsdl file on my local dir, linked with the multiple xsds.

```
1:[Expected element ''GroupNumber@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' instead of ''GroupType@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' here in element GroupCustomer@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community]. 
2:[Expected element ''GroupNumber@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' instead of ''GroupName@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' here in element GroupCustomer@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community]. 
3:[Expected element ''GroupNumber@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' instead of ''GroupCustomerCode@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' here in element GroupCustomer@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community]. 
4:[Expected element ''GroupNumber@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' instead of ''SimpleProperty@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community'' here in element GroupCustomer@http://www.herman.com/bme/cbsinterface/community].
```

Below is my code xml snip.

```
<xs:complexType name="GroupCustomer">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ParentGroupCustomerID">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="23"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ParentGroupNumber" type="community:GroupNumberType"/>
         <xs:element name="GroupNumber">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="community:GroupNumberType">
                  <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="GroupType" type="community:GroupCustomer"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GroupName">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GroupCustomerCode">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="23"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GroupCustomerID">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="23"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RegisterNo">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="23"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MaxCountOfCug" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MaxCountOfGroupOut" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MaxHuntingList" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="QuotaAmount" type="common:Balance"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BelToAreaID">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="SimpleProperty"
                     type="common:SimpleProperty"/>
         <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="RatingGroupList">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="RatingGroup" type="xs:int"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="OfficeZoneInfo">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="CallingCellID">
                     <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                           <xs:maxLength value="19"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                     </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:element>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element default="0" minOccurs="0" name="MaxMemNumber" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TimeZone" type="xs:int"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema says that the GroupNumber element is mandatory; your error messages say that it's not present in the instance document (or if it is present, then it's in the wrong place).